# GraphQL query - how to reuse inline fragments field on different types

Tags: javascript, graphql

I have a working graphQL query which looks something like this

```
query( $ownerId: ID!){
    getPets(ownerId:$ownerId){
        id,
        ownerDescription
    ...on Dog {
            id
            name
        }
    ...on Cat {
            id
            name

        }
    }
}
```

What I want (but do not know how to achieve) is following

```
query( $ownerId: ID!){
    getPets(ownerId:$ownerId){
        id,
        ownerDescription
    ...on (Dog | Cat) {
            id
            name
        }
}
```

Is it even possible to reuse fields, in a way I want?

I have no control over the schema, so I hope to find a solution that can be implemented in the same place, where I do query.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the schema. GraphQL supports interface inheritance. So both `Dog` and `Cat` could inherit from, say `Pet` with the properties `id` and `name`. In that scenario you could refer the the parent instead

```
   ... on Pet {
     id
     name
   }
```

Comment: I have no control over the schema, and as of now, there is no interface that contains all the properties I want to query for. 
So I hoped to find a solution which can be implemented in the same place, where I do query.

Comment: I updated the question with this limitation. Thank for the proposing valid solution, albeit not for this case.